# Executing a procedure based on the number of occurrences of an element in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, count

I am a first-year A-Level student and I've got a problem.
This is my list (context - it's a hand in the card game rummy, the program I'm making):

```
hand = [(1, '-', '3', 'Hearts'), (2, '-', '6', 'Diamonds'), (3, '-', '10', 'Spades'), (4, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'), (5, '-', '7', 'Hearts'), (6, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'), (7, '-', '3', 'Diamonds')]
```

I need to write something to determine when the game has been won (i.e. 4 cards in the same suit or consecutive numbers) and I had wanted to use an if statement essentially saying: "If there are 4 elements with the same suit then [game ending procedure].

I have tried using:

```
if sum(x.count('Spades') for x in list) == 4:
```

without much luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What excatly does `(1, '-', '3', 'Hearts')` represent?

Comment: @schwobaseggl - The index[0], in this case 1, represents the position in the hand, which comes in handy when choosing which card to discard. Index[1], the '-',  just separates the position from the forthcoming info. Index[2][3] is the name of the card, in this instance the 3 of Hearts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum` as follows:

```
if sum(x[3] == 'Spades' for x in hand) == 4:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most concise way, but it might be easier to understand how it works:

```py
if len([x for x in hand if x[3] == 'Spades']) == 4:
```